# Clickable columns to redirect to another page amcharts stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

i am using stacked bar chart in amcharts am5
want to add url's for each column bar and redirecting on a url when someone clicks on a column bar
There are some posts on the stackoverflow on how to add links to columns, but they are for Amcharts4 and don't work on Amcharts5. .

[Codepen demo from the site](https://codepen.io/Kavinda-nuwan-the-scripter/pen/dyQGjvj)

I will appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do that by adding

```
/*   Mouse pointer change for columns */
series.columns.template.events.on("pointerover", function (ev) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
    });
    series.columns.template.events.on("pointerout", function (ev) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    });
    /*   column click to url */
series.columns.template.events.on("click", function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.url);
   window.location.assign(ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.url); }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).